# 1F95-1291 White rogers thermostats run ac while furnace on

Tags: heating, cooling

I have two 1F95-1291 White rogers thermostats for 2 furnaces and ac's. While both furnaces run, 1 ac comes on each morning for a set time. What's wrong?

Comment: `What's wrong?` we have no idea. What are the settings on the thermostat ?

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing wires from wall to thermostat base?